# how switch to another fragment ViewPager on click button from first fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working with a simple app with Bottom Navigation View, i create four fragment in one activity on a viewpager, then i use *bottomNavigationView* to switch between fragment and it's working fine,

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.navigation_home:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_category:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_cart:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                            break;
                        case R.id.navigation_profil:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            }
            else
            {
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
            }
            Log.d("page",""+position);
            bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
            prevMenuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
```

my problem is,
i create a button in first fragment and i want to switch to another fragment when the button clicked, How can i do this?
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> make your viewpager public static

**public static Viewpager viewPager;**

> then on button click  apply this code :-

```
MainActivity.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
//(here MainActivity is your main activity where you are using viewpager)
```